# How to create an EventBridge (CloudWatch Events) rule and add it to a Lambda function as a trigger using CDK?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cdk, aws-event-bridge

I'm trying to create an EventBridge (CloudWatch Events) Rule and have that rule added as a trigger to an existing Lambda function.

```
    const notificationFunction = lambda.Function.fromFunctionArn(this,
      'DevopsNotificationLambda',
      _props.notificationLambdaArn
    );
    const rule = new Rule(this, `${stackPrefix}-EventRule`, {
      eventPattern: {
        source: ['aws.codepipeline'],
        detailType: ['CodePipeline Pipeline Execution State Change'],
        detail: {pipeline: [pipeline.pipelineName]}
      },
    });
    notificationFunction.addPermission(`${stackPrefix}-CloudWatchPermission`, {
      principal: new ServicePrincipal('events.amazonaws.com'),
      sourceArn: rule.ruleArn
    });
    rule.addTarget(new LambdaFunction(notificationFunction));
```

The code creates the EventBridge with the Lambda target correctly, but it doesn't add the trigger to the actual Lambda. I have to manually add the EventBridge to the Lambda through the AWS Web Console.

[image: add trigger]

Seems like it's not enough to add the Lambda as a target to the Event Rule. How should I add the Event Rule as a trigger to the Lambda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Importing existing external resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/resources.html#resources_importing) in the CDK Developer Guide.

> Although you can use an imported resource anywhere, you cannot modify the imported resource. For example, calling addToResourcePolicy (Python: add_to_resource_policy) on an imported s3.Bucket does nothing.

You cannot add a trigger to `notificationFunction` from the CDK stack because `notificationFunction` is an external resource.

Answer (score 0):

```
// create lambda function
const notificationFunction = lambda.Function.fromFunctionArn(this,
      'DevopsNotificationLambda',
      _props.notificationLambdaArn
    );

// create event rule
let eventRule = new Rule(this, `${props.APPNAME}-${props.STAGE}-eventRuleName`, {
      schedule: Schedule.cron({ minute: "0/10" }), // schedule the event as needed
      targets: [notificationFunction]
    });
```

1. Create the lambda function
2. Create an event rule with the lambda as target and schedule the event as needed.

If the lambda is being created in a different stack - use the lambdaARN to create the lambda function in the present stack and use it as target.

Expected Result - Lambda endpoint being hit at regular intervals as mentioned in the event rule.